# Улучшить качество кода php

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Решил поучится php, делаю свою первую полноценную программу.
Но слышал что много встроенных if это неправильно. Но я не понимаю как подругому сделать?
Подскажите. Вот код программы:

```
        <?php

if (!isset($conf['versionsetup']) && $conf['versionsetup'] != 1) {

    // Добавляем основную версию сайта

    $addpage = $page->addPage('Основная версия', 'main', $html, 1);
    if ($addpage == "uniname" or $addpage == "") die('Ошибка имя страницы не уникальное');
    if ($addpage == "unimeta") die('Ошибка мета тэга');
    if ($addpage == "noacess") die('Доступ запрещен');
    header("Refresh:0");
}
else {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {

        // Выводим главную

        if ($pages[$conf['main_page']]['active'] != 0) {
            $isbetaon = strripos($pages[$conf['main_page']]['betaId'], "true");

            // Проверяем наличие беты

            if ($pages[$conf['main_page']]['betaId'] != "" and $isbetaon != 0) {
                $rand = rand(0, 1);
                if ($rand == 1) {
                    $main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], false);
                }
                else {
                    $main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], true);
                }
            }
            else {
                $main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], false);
            }

            echo $main;
        }
        else {
            die('Страница не активирована');
        }
    }

    // Выводим нужную версию

    elseif ($_GET['v']) {
        if (getMeta($pages, $_GET['v'])) {
            $pagemeta = getMeta($pages, $_GET['v']);
        }

        // Проверяем страницу на активность

        if ($pages[$pagemeta]['active'] != 0) {
            $isbetaon = strripos($pages[$pagemeta]['betaId'], "true");

            // Проверяем наличие беты

            if ($pages[$pagemeta]['betaId'] != "" and $isbetaon != 0) {
                $rand = rand(0, 1);
                if ($rand == 1) {
                    $version = $page->getPage($pagemeta, false);
                }
                else {
                    $version = $page->getPage($pagemeta, true);
                }
            }
            else {
                $version = $page->getPage($pagemeta, false);
            }

            echo $version;
        }
        else {
            die('Страница не активирована');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно лучше вначале с форматирования кода начать? Без обид, но в этой каше мало что понятно.

Comment: самое первое, что я бы сделал, так это некоторые "тела if'ов" повыносил в отдельные функции. Вот к примеру "проверка беты".

Comment: Советую прочитать, как правильно строить навигацию (роутинг), так как в вашем случае очень много одинаковых телодвижений, которые можно заменять 1 строчкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тоже не понимаю, почему много ifов, это неправильно... Иногда, даже, пожалуй, очень часто, без них никак...

Ну а насчет сокращения кода могу предложить такой вариант.
Меняем вот эту часть:

```
if ($pages[$conf['main_page']]['betaId'] != "" and $isbetaon != 0) {
    $rand = rand(0, 1);
    if ($rand == 1) {
        $main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], false);
    } else {
        $main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], true);
    }
} else {
    $main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], false);
}
```

Вот на это:

```
$main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], false);
if ($pages[$conf['main_page']]['betaId'] != "" and $isbetaon != 0 and rand(0, 1) != 1) {
    $main = $page->getPage($conf['main_page'], true);
}
```

Т.е. в `$main` сразу записываем значение `getPage()`, и изменяем его только если это необходимо по условиям.

У Вас похожая конструкция используется также в определении `$version`, так что это достаточно сократит код.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему множество ifов, это неправильно, но это точно некрасиво. Простая рекомендация, которая бросается в глаза: переменную `$addpage` можно проверять с помощью `switch () { case ... }` (http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php).

Моей рекомендацией будет: почитать про ООП Паттерны проектирования для PHP. Они помогут избавиться от бесконечных ifов. Этого можно достичь, в основном, с помощью полиморфизма и различных методов работы с ассоциативными массивами.

Например, можно начать с Хабра: https://habrahabr.ru/post/214285/